# Existence of $n$ such that $a^n=a$ for all $a$ in $Z_m$

Tags: ring-theory, finite-rings

This is a question from *Contemporary Abstract Algebra* which asks:

> Find an integer $n > 1$ such that $a^n = a$ for all $a$ in $Z_6$.
>   Show that no such $n$ exists for $Z_m$ when $m$ is divisible by the
>   square of some prime.

I could search for $n=3$ in case of $Z_6$. But I am not able to proceed with the proof the second part. Being a beginner I don't have much idea. Some help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: when you wrote $n=4$, did you mean $n=3$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thanks for pointing out it was a typo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $m$ be any positive integer. Then $\varphi(m)$ denotes the number of integers in the set $\{ 1, \ldots, m \}$ that are relatively prime to $m$.

Thus we have
$$ \varphi(1) = 1, \ \varphi(2) = 1, \ \varphi(3) = 2, \ \varphi(4) = 2, \ \varphi(5) = 4, $$
and so on.

If $p$ is any prime, then we have
$$ \varphi(p) = p-1. $$

If 
$$ m = p_1^{\alpha_1} \cdots p_r^{\alpha_r}, $$
where $p_1 <  \cdots < p_r$ are distinct primes and $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_r$ are the positive integeral exponents, is the unique prime factorisation of $m$, then we have the formula
$$ \varphi(m) = m \left( 1 - \frac{1}{p_1} \right) \cdots \left( 1 - \frac{1}{p_r} \right). $$

If $a$ is any integer relatively prime to $m$, then we have the Euler's formula
$$ a^{\varphi(m)} \equiv 1 (\mod m), $$
and so
$$ a^{1+\varphi(m)} \equiv a (\mod m), $$

Finally, in $Z_m$, two elements $a$ and $b$ are equal if and only if the integers $a$ and $b$ are congruent $\mod m$.

Thus if $m$ is a prime, then 
$$ a^{1+\varphi(m)} = a$$
in $\mathbb{Z}_m$.

If $m = p^2 r$, where $p$ is a prime and $r$ is any positive integer, then $p \in \mathbb{Z}_m$ and we notice that 
$$ p^2 \neq p, $$
and hence
$$ p^3 = pp^2 \neq p, $$
for otherwise we would get $$ p^2 = 1,$$
that is,
$$ p^2 \equiv 1 (\mod p^2 r), $$
which is the same as 
$$ p^2 r \, | \, \left( p^2 - 1 \right), $$
and so
$$ p^2 - 1 = p^2rq, $$
where $q$ is an integer (and of course $q > 0$), which implies that 
$$ 1 = p^2 - p^2rq = p^2 (1 - rq), $$
which clearly is impossible since both $r$ and $q$ are positive integers.

Continuing in this way if $n > 3$ and if $p^n = p$ in $\mathbb{Z}_m$, then we would get
$$ p^{n-1} = 1$$ in $\mathbb{Z}_m$, that is,
$$ p^{n-1} \equiv 1 ( \mod m), $$
and so
$$ p^{n-1} - 1 = p^2rq_0, $$
where $q_0$ is an integer (greater than $0$ of course), and thence
$$ 1 =  p^2 \left(1 -  r q_0 \right), $$
which is impossible since both $q_0$ and $r$ are positive integers.

Comment: Please edit the typo here: "If $m=p^{2}r$, where $r$ is a prime and $q$ is any , then $p∈Z_m$ and we notice that.." Thanks for the detailing.

Comment: @ShatabdiSinha  thank you for pointing out the mistakes. I've made the corrections.